# Prevent overlaping loop cuts from merging

Tags: topology

I'm trying to create two parallel loop cuts on a pyramid. The way I saw how to do it is to first make one loop cut in the middle of the pyramid which will be vertical to the base, then do a second loop cut and push it against the first one to be parallel also to the base. The problem I'm having is that when I push the second loop cut against the first, the two loop cuts seem to merge together because when I try to move the selected loop cut, then both cuts seem to be moved around.

How can I prevent the second loop cut from being merged with the one it's on top of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely one of these two options is on:

- Proportional editing, on left and the first edge loop is influenced when you move the second one
- Auto merge vertices, on right and the vertices were actually merged when you moved the second one onto the first

[image]

Comment: Yep proportional editing was the problem. What does that actually do? After I separated the two edges and enabled it again, they didn't seem to move together again

Comment: Proportional editing allows to influence nearby vertices when you move some. Have a look at the doc here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html#proportional-editing